# Position sidebar mdl-drawer under the navigation panel instead of on top of it

Tags: material-design-lite

In Material Design Lite how do you specify the position of elements? I would like to show the sidebar under the navigation panel not on top of it like it is by default now: http://www.getmdl.io/components/#layout-section/layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something support out of the box since it means the design will no longer adhere to Material Design. So if you wish to do this, you need to target the drawer in your own CSS and specify a top margin so it will sit below the navbar. Then deal with anything else that may break from the movement (I don't believe anything should though.)